# Strange droppable Hover-Effect with draggable Helper

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, droppable

I'm testing around with jQuery draggables and droppables and have a question about the hover behaviour of droppable and clones of a draggable.

The documentation says that the draggable item has to overlap the droppable at least 50% to fire the over-event (default tolerance). This works exactly like described if I drag the item itself.

If I drag a clone of the item, the 50% rule doesn't work. In this case the clone has to overlap the droppable quite 100% if I'm dragging vertically from the top. If I'm dragging the clone from the left side, the hover-event will fire very early at 10%.

How does this come up?

```js
$("#eins").draggable({
            helper: "clone",
            opacity: 0.7,
            drag: function(event,ui) {
                     $(ui.helper).addClass("clone")
                },
            stop: function (event, ui) {
                    console.log("Dragging stoped")
                }
})

$("#zwei").droppable({
            classes: {"ui-droppable-hover": "draggableHover"},
            tolerance: "intersect",
            over: function(event, ui) {
                    console.log("hover")
                },
            drop: function (event, ui) {
                    console.log("dropped")
                }
})
```

```css
#eins, .clone {
   background: coral;
   height: 100px;
   width: 100px;
   margin: 0px;
}

#zwei {
   background:lightgreen;
   height:100px;
   width: 100px;
   margin: 0px;
}

.draggableHover {
   background: rgb(230, 250, 230) !important;
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<div id="eins">
   eins
</div>
<div id="zwei">
   zwei
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution: class="eins" intead of id="eins".